# Reading multiple files into a single file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file, for-loop, iteration

I'm attempting to pull data in from 25 different files and combine them into one single file.  Each of the files is in a different directory and I've been able to create the loop that goes through the directories to pull the specific file in.  However, within that file there are 6 doubles I want to read in and I want each of these doubles numbered accordingly (1, 2, 3,...25).  What is the best way to do this without brute force copy and pasting the code 25 times, if there is such a way?  Everything I've seen is that this is considered dynamically creating variables and not a good practice.  The unfortunate thing is I then need to do that 21 more times.

Example code typed in:

```
for nsub=1:numel(subdirectories)
    %loading file into workspace
    load(fullfile('myfiledirectory',subdirectories(nsub),'2627N.mat'));
%for N=1:length(subdirectories) % 25 subdirectories
day=soundspeed(1,25)
for i=1:25
    day{i}=1:i;
end
end
```

where I want day{1} to be the first day, day{2} to be the second and so forth.  Day in this case is a 21x6 double.
Ideally, I'd like to save this as a big .mat file that I can call the individual pieces of the arrays to perform statistical analysis (mean, std dev, MLR, SLR, etc) on them.  Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are pretty much there; what exactly do you feel like you are missing?  I see that you have 1) a for loop to load files out of each directory, 2) saving data from that into a variable called `day`.  You want to be careful that you don't overwrite `day` each time through the loop; so don't do `day=soundspeed(1,25)`, but do `day{i} = soundspeed(1,25)` and then update `i` so it only increments once each time through the loop.

Comment: @articmac I knew I was close with it and I was able to just dynamically load it.  I was trying to avoid that, but I just got frustrated and wanted to get the data into MATLAB and it seems to be working at the moment.  But if that doesn't work for me, I'd want to put the second for loop above the `day{i}=soundspeed(1,25)`  in order to avoid overwriting day each time, correct?  Thanks.